# How to select every first items of multiple blocks (html, javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, selectors-api

I'm trying to select every first item of a serie of multiple blocks but I can't figure out how to do this :(

Here is an exemple of what I've tried :

```js
let everyItems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.block .item'));
let firstItems = Array.from(everyItems[0]);

document.getElementById('every1stItem').innerText = firstItems.innerText;
```

```html
<div calss="block"><b>First block</b>
  <div class="item">Item 1.1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1.2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1.3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1.4</div>
 </div>
 <div calss="block"><b>Second block</b>
  <div class="item">Item 2.1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2.2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2.3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2.4</div>
 </div>
 <div calss="block"><b>Third block</b>
  <div class="item">Item 3.1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3.2</div>
  <sdivan class="item">Item 3.3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3.4</div>
 </div>
 
 <div>
  <b>The first item of every block is :</b>
  <div id="every1stItem"></div>
 </div>
 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thank you for helping me out !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
let everyItems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.block'));

let firstItems = everyItems.map(i => i.children[1].innerText).join(', ')

document.getElementById('every1stItem').innerText = firstItems;
```

```html
<div class="block"><b>First block</b>
  <div class="item">Item 1.1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1.2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1.3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1.4</div>
 </div>
 <div class="block"><b>Second block</b>
  <div class="item">Item 2.1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2.2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2.3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2.4</div>
 </div>
 <div class="block"><b>Third block</b>
  <div class="item">Item 3.1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3.2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3.3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3.4</div>
 </div>
 
 <div>
  <b>The first item of every block is :</b>
  <div id="every1stItem"></div>
 </div>
 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you ! Do you know if there is a way to change every first item ? (to make that "Item X.1" stays within it's div but changes for exemple to "test" ?

Answer (score 0):

using `:nth-child(n)` selector

```js
let everyItems = $('.item:nth-child(2)');
$('#every1stItem').html(everyItems)
```

```html
<div>
  <b>The first item of every block is :</b>
  <div id="every1stItem"></div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="block"><b>First block</b>
  <div class="item">Item 1.1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1.2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1.3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 1.4</div>
</div>
<div class="block"><b>Second block</b>
  <div class="item">Item 2.1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2.2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2.3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2.4</div>
</div>
<div class="block"><b>Third block</b>
  <div class="item">Item 3.1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3.2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3.3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3.4</div>
</div>


 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.queryselector(".className")` returns the first element with the class className